# How to pause and play canvas

Tags: javascript, html, button, canvas

the code is here > https://dotgame-io.glitch.me/index.js I would like to make a pause and play button in top right corner of game, with in the canvas, it will be one button that switches from pause symbol(to pause) to play symbol(to resume).

Comment: anyone working on this?

Comment: can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is have a Boolean variable that sets the state of whether the canvas is "playing" or not which is toggled by the play button. Then, in the function that updates the canvas, only update the canvas if that variable is true (so put the canvas updates inside an if statement).

Comment: what code would i use to do this? I'm a bit new to canvas, all i need is the code to pause and play it on click, thx, Dot.